# What are the pet health considerations in using fipronil for treating parasites?

Tags: health, fleas

[Fipronil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fipronil) is a topical flea and other parasite treatment for pets.

Is there any evidence supporting health concerns in humans or pets with the use of Fipronil for treating fleas? What dosage/application rate is documented as safe or unsafe?